# UIBarButtonItem in storyboards

Tags: xcode, view, storyboard

the master detail application included when you use Storyboards this code in view did load.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
```

i want to use this like in same project with .xib'S

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showGegenstellenView)];
```

the problem is that i can't implement this code in the storyboard project. I can't find help special for storyboards...

```
-(void)showGegenstellenView{
GegenstellenViewController *gegenstellenViewController = [[GegenstellenViewController alloc]initWithMasterController:self Gegenstellen:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:gegenstellenViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Finally I want to click in the table view the add button and a view comes with a formular.
All this works in the project with xib's i have. But i want it with storyboards! I have no problem when u want see the xib project via team viewer or as sib by mail.

Best Regards
John